# Angular looks for a route in the DI tree

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to redirect to a route in my guard, but Angular try to get a dependency, with the StaticInjector, using the url route as token. I've never seen something like this and I don't understand what is the deal between routes and DI.

The exception is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[/unauthorized]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[/unauthorized]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for /unauthorized!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[/unauthorized]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[/unauthorized]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for /unauthorized!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8399)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8356)
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8399)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8356)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3815)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

Here's the Guard Code:

```
return this.permissionService.checkAuthorization(permissionName)
  .then(permissionResult => {
    if (this.failUrl && !permissionResult) {
      this.router.navigate([this.failUrl]);
    }
    return permissionResult;
  });
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Please add in your Guard Code as well.

Comment: `return this.permissionService
      .checkAuthorization(permissionName)
      .then(permissionResult => {
        if (this.failUrl && !permissionResult) {
          this.router.navigate([this.failUrl]);
        }

        return permissionResult;
      });`

Comment: Is `permissionService` added to the `providers` array in your AppModule?

Comment: Here is it, I use a Module Loaded url to navigate when the user hasn't permissions to the route

Comment: @SiddAjmera it does, it's not about the service dependency

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` to your guard code for the `if` condition.

Comment: It doesn't works

Comment: Consider creating a StackBlitz in that case.

Comment: Indeed, the guard never gets executed

Comment: I've found the bug. I was using useExisting in my PermissionModule to inject the FAIL_URL in the forRoot, that's why in the error the StaticInjector was looking for "/unauthorized", I replace it for useValue and everything is fine now